# T-SQL Verify each character of each value in a column against values of another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in a database with a column which has values like XX-xx-cccc-ff-gg. Let's assume this is table ABC and column is called ABC_FORMAT_STR. In another table, ABC_FORMAT_ELEMENTS I have a column called CHARS with values like, A, B, C, D... X, Y, Z, a, d, f, g, x, y, z etc. (please don't assume I have all ASCII values there, it's mainly some letters and numbers plus some special characters like *, ;, -, & etc.).

I need to add a constraint in [ABC].[ABC_FORMAT_STR] column, in such a way so, each and every character of every value of that column, should exist in [ABC_FORMAT_ELEMENTS].[CHARS]

Is the possible? Can someone help me with this?
Thank you very much in advance.

This is an example with simple names, keeping the names of the object above for clarity:

### Example

```
SELECT [ABC_FORMAT_STR] FROM [ABC]

Nick
George
Adam
```

---

```
SELECT [CHARS] FROM [ABC_FORMAT_ELEMENTS]

A
G
N
a
c
e
g
i
k
o
r
```

After the coonstraint:

```
SELECT [ABC_FORMAT_STR] FROM [ABC]

Nick
George
```

Note on the result:
"Adam" cannot be included because "d" and "m" character are not in [ABC_FORMAT_ELEMENTS] table.

Comment: It *is* possible, with a user defined scalar function. If you're not on 2019 and you can manage to inline the function there I would be wary and adding such a `CONSTRAINT` could impact the performance of your DML statements significantly.

Comment: @Lamu Thank you sir for the input, in all honesty I will need help. The two tables are not being updated frequently, as a matter of fact it's quite rare, but nonetheless this check is a requirement, and I couldn't manage to do because is based on a character-by-character check against a set of allowed characters..

Comment: You could do it with logic in a function you check on your insert/update statments or with the logic in a trigger, using something like `exists where not exists`

Comment: If you want ping a user, @Nick , you need to spell their alias correctly. Lamu won't ping me.

Comment: As for the problem, take the time to add some sample data to your question; that will help us help you.

Comment: Take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=45603fff0d64187444cc20f850c7978e

Comment: What do you want to happen when a change to `[ABC_FORMAT_ELEMENTS].[CHARS]` invalidates some existing rows in `[ABC].[ABC_FORMAT_STR]`? Do rows vanish from `[ABC].[ABC_FORMAT_STR]`? Is the change to `[ABC_FORMAT_ELEMENTS].[CHARS]` rolled back?

Comment: What is your SQL Server version (SELECT @@VERSION;)?

Comment: @HABO : I actually do not want to be able to input any records that violate this rule.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB4583458) - 15.0.2080.9 (X64) Developer Edition (64-bit)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Sir, I think you nailed it.. Testing now again but I already replicated the result wanted. THANK YOU !!!!!

Comment: @Nick Always happy to help

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple and most natural solution based on the `TRANSLATE()` function.

It will work starting from SQL Server 2017 onwards.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @ABC TABLE  (ABC_FORMAT_STR VARCHAR(50));  
INSERT INTO @ABC VALUES
('Nick'),
('George'),
('Adam');
 
DECLARE @ABC_FORMAT_ELEMENTS TABLE (CHARS CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO @ABC_FORMAT_ELEMENTS VALUES
('A'), ('G'), ('N'),('a'), ('c'), ('e'), ('g'),
('i'), ('k'), ('o'), ('r');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT a.*
    , t1.legitChars
    , t2.badChars
FROM @ABC AS a
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT STRING_AGG(CHARS, '') FROM @ABC_FORMAT_ELEMENTS) AS t1(legitChars)
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRANSLATE(a.ABC_FORMAT_STR, t1.legitChars, SPACE(LEN(t1.legitChars)))) AS t2(badChars)
WHERE TRIM(t2.badChars) = '';
```

**Output**

```
+----------------+-------------+----------+
| ABC_FORMAT_STR | legitChars  | badChars |
+----------------+-------------+----------+
| Nick           | AGNacegikor |          |
| George         | AGNacegikor |          |
+----------------+-------------+----------+
```

**Output with WHERE clause commented out**

Just to see why the row with the 'Adam' value was filtered out.

```
+----------------+-------------+----------+
| ABC_FORMAT_STR | legitChars  | badChars |
+----------------+-------------+----------+
| Nick           | AGNacegikor |          |
| George         | AGNacegikor |          |
| Adam           | AGNacegikor |  d m     |
+----------------+-------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample data, here's one method to identify valid/invalid rows in `ABC`. You could easily adapt this to be part of a trigger that can check inserted or updated rows in `inserted` and `rollback` if any rows violate the criteria.

This uses a tally/numbers table (very often used for splitting strings), This defines one using a CTE but a permanent solution would have a permanent numbers table to reuse.

The logic is to split the strings into rows and then count the rows that exist in the lookup table and reject any with a count of rows that is less than the length of the string.

```
with
    numbers (n) as (select top 100 Row_Number() over (order by (select null)) from sys.messages ),
    strings as (
        select a.ABC_FORMAT_STR, Count(*) over(partition by a.ABC_FORMAT_STR) n
        from abc a cross join numbers n
        where n.n<=Len(a.ABC_FORMAT_STR)
        and exists (select * from ABC_FORMAT_ELEMENTS e where e.chars=Substring(a.ABC_FORMAT_STR,n,1))
    )

select ABC_FORMAT_STR
from strings
where Len(ABC_FORMAT_STR)=n
group by ABC_FORMAT_STR

/* change to where Len(ABC_FORMAT_STR) <> n  to find rows that aren't allowed */
```

See this [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bc0ac2e5aa09d93bfabd3174163afa5e)

Comment: This is beautiful and also truly advanced (I need just a bit to understand it). THANK YOU for sharing your expertise, much appreciated.

Comment: Dear all. THANK YOU ! Both solutions worked, with Mr John Cappelletti's yesterday being first in submission, and @Stu as well after that. Kindly help me to accept the first answer, since it is only fair the first accurate response to be chosen as answer so that others can benefit as well.
THANK YOU so much.